# Seems like python is partial

Tags: python

The following is a function I created, and put it in a file called last_function.py

```
from tkinter import*


def new_gui(app,sound_file,mixer):

    track=mixer.Sound(sound_file)
    def track_toggle():
        if ballCheckbutton.get()==1:

            track.play(loops=-1)
        else:
            track.stop()

    ballCheckbutton=IntVar()    
    c1=Checkbutton(app,text="check me out",command=track_toggle,variable=ballCheckbutton)
    c1.pack(side=LEFT)

    ballScale=DoubleVar()

    def ScaleVolume(v):
        track.set_volume(ballScale.get())

    ballScale.set(track.get_volume())
    s1=Scale(app,variable=ballScale,resolution=0.1,command=ScaleVolume,orient=HORIZONTAL,from_=0.0,to=1.0,label="volume")
    s1.pack()
```

and this is the file i use.. to call the code and run it..

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame.mixer
from last_function import*

app=Tk()
mixer=pygame.mixer
mixer.init()
new_gui(app,"49119_M_RED_HardBouncer.wav",mixer)


def close():
    mixer.stop()
    app.destroy()

app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",close)
app.mainloop()
```

Everything works fine.. but my query is...

1> Why can't I remove `from tkinter import*` from the last_function file.. cause anyway it's got that on the top of the file that's calling it right. Why do I get an error saying IntVar() not defined.

2> Why do I have to pass `mixer` as a parameter in the function? can the function not inherit it directly from `import pygame.mixer`that's on top of the file calling it?
 What I mean to say is. THERE ARE TKINTER COMPONENTS ALSO BEING USED, BUT I DON'T PASS TKINTER AS A PARAMETER.. Do I ! then why is there this... selective parameter assignment??

I'm really confused!!!

Comment: Please don't shout, even if you're that confused.

Comment: This is likely to be a circular import error, indicating a design flaw somewhere.  In general you should avoid `from x import *` unless you absolutely have to use it. It clutters your name space and can shadow built ins (`from os import *` shadows the built in `open()` for example. The built-in returns a file handle, `os.open` returns an int).

Comment: @g.d.d.c- that's enlightening thanks.. I'll use FQN's from now!!

Comment: @g.d.d.c doesn't that belong in the answers?

Comment: @truthreality - possibly, though I haven't answered the question, simply made a postulation.  I'd need to spend more time to figure out where / whether it actually is a circular import error.  I just know that when you can _only_ make something work by doing `from x import *` that's usually the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1> Why can't i remove from tkinter
>   import* from the last_function file..
>   cause anyway it's got that on the top
>   of the file that's calling it
>   right.Why do i get an error saying
>   IntVar() not defined

The Python "import" follows the same scoping rules as the rest of the Python language. By "import" at the top of your second files does not make the Tkinter namespace available to the last_function.py module.  Tkinter also needs to be imported there.

> 2>why do i have to pass mixer as a
>   parameter in the function? can the
>   function not inherit it directly from
>   import pygame.mixerthat's on top of
>   the file calling it? WHAT I MEAN TO
>   SAY IS. THERE ARE TKINTER COMPONENTS
>   ALSO BEING USED,BUT I DON'T PASS
>   TKINTER AS A PARAMETER.. DO I!! then
>   why is there this.. selective
>   parameter assignment??

With the way you have this coded, you need to pass mixer because you are modifying it in your second file with:

```
mixer.init()
```

If you reimported mixer in your last_function.py, you would be getting another instance of mixer and not the one previously imported.  There is nothing selective about this since both of your files have the Tkinter namespace imported.

**You should try and re-factor this code to avoid having to import Tkinter into two modules and having to init mixer in one module and pass it to another.**

Comment: @Mark-i think your previous explanation was better( though it was a bit complicated) but.. i got it!! thanks..